# How do I set up my LaTeX document to enable me to cite from my BibTeX bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

This may be an overly simplistic question but please bear with me...

I have a BibTeX bibliography containing all of my references, set up using BibDesk. I am now trying to cite these references in my LaTeX documents. Following the advice on the LaTeX wikibooks page, I have included the following lines into my LaTeX document...

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{/Users/Graeme/Documents/References/BIBliography.bib}
```

... where `BIBliography` is my `.bib` file, created in BibDesk.

Unfortunately, when I cite something in the document, using `\cite{citekey}` and typeset the document, the log tells me that there were undefined references. In the `.pdf` that is produced, there is a `[?]` where the references should be.

Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to store my `.bib` for in a particular location? I know there can be some errors that mean you need to typeset the document several times, but I have tried countless times to no avail.

I would be very grateful if someone could help out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that after every change in your BibTeX file you do this:

1. Run LaTeX
2. Run BibTeX
3. Run LaTeX
4. Run LaTeX

Comment: Or use `arara`!

Comment: Install `arara` and then add `% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{report}
...` into your document.

Answer (score 3):

You can do such things in a simplified way using the automation tool `arara` by @Paulo Cereda. First you have to install arara after downloading it from [Paulo Cereda's git hub space](https://github.com/cereda/arara). Then in your document just before the `\documentclass{article}` add the following lines:

```
% arara: pdflatex 
% arara: bibtex 
% arara: pdflatex 
% arara: pdflatex 
\documentclass{article}
.
.
.
```

Let us say that you have saved your document with the name `mydoc.tex`. From command prompt,  issue a command

```
arara full path to your document\mydoc.tex
```

Arara will take care of running `pdflatex`, then `bibtex`, `pdflatex` and again `pdflatex` by a single command.

For more details, refer to the `arara` user manual. If you are using a specific editor, you may seek help from this site for adding a tool bar button to your editor using which you can run `arara`.