# Biblatex still won't print bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I have read all the related questions and taken all the suggested steps (well, the ones that had anything to do with my situation since for example I am not using `XeLaTeX`).  As far as I can see, this file ought to produce a pdf with one citation in it and a bibliography with that entry.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{FefCF}

\printbibliography    
\end{document}
```

Instead it produces a pdf with the name `FefCF` printed in boldface and no bibliography.

I am using `TeXworks` and have run both `BibTeX` and pdfLaTex+MakeIndex+BibTeX repeatedly in many combinations.

To be clear, the reference FefCF is indeed in the file refs.bib (and has been used many time with `BibTeX`) and it is in the same folder as this file, namely `C:/Users/Colin/Documents/TeX Files`.  I have also tried the full location name `C:/Users/Colin/Documents/TeX Files/refs.bib` to specify the bib resource.  That makes no difference.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\usepackage[]{biblatex}` is not a proper call to `biblatex` especially if you want to run it with BibTeX. Try `\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}` instead; or install `biber` and try `\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}` (then, of course, you will have to run `pdlfatex` + `biber` + `pdflatex` + `pdflatex`).

Comment: @moewe Thanks.  Biber is installed and I have tried this with biber and bibtex.  TeXworks does not give me an option of running biber the way it does bibtex. Anyway no combination of pdflatex and bibtex has worked for me yet.

Comment: Mhhhh. What is the (`.log`) output of the LaTeX and BibTeX/biber runs respectively? Note that if at all the exact document you posted only works with biber (I might have replied glibly when I said your call was not proper as it should work with biber). For biber in TeXworks see [How to automate using biber in MiKTeX-TeXworks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69705/35864) and [Dummies Guide to Biber](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63308/35864)

Comment: I'd also consider using the wonderful `arara` tool to automate the process, as shown in [How do I set up my LaTeX document to enable me to cite from my BibTeX bibliography?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66201)

Comment: @moewe  Thanks. This is the third time I've spent more than a few hours working on Biblatex and I'm sure I will get it to work some day.  But for now (with 72 hours to get a book review to a journal) I'll go back to the familiar frustrations of BibTeX.

Comment: If you were thinking of using `biblatex` in a submission to a journal, you might want to read this [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864) (it does not look that bright).

Comment: Ah, thanks.  Bad news.  Not so bad for me since I have yet to master biblatex anyway. But I'm sure in the long run biblatex will get ahead of bibtex in publishing.

Comment: Having read the comments in the question linked above one might pessimistically suspect it will be quite a long run indeed.

Comment: What exactly worked for you in the accepted answer?

Comment: @Ricky It persuaded me that I do not want further answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The main hurdles with biblatex/biber are:

1. You are not calling biber at all but bibtex (check the `.blg` file if it starts with "biber" or "bibtex").
2. biber fails due to a problem with the cache files. Run `biber --cache` on the command line and delete the folder you get as output.
3. biber fails due to an error in your bib file: Check the `blg` file.

Comment: Is 1 a problem when I have set backend=bibtex?

Comment: @ColinMcLarty It should not be at all, except, of course, for cases in which biber is necessary. Remember to remove all auxiliary files though.

Comment: @colinMcLarty: 1 + 2 are biber specific.

Comment: FYI, I had error 3 because of an empty entry in my .bib file that I had not seen.

Answer (score 12):

`Biblatex` now uses `Biber` as default backend. It used to use `BibTeX` before.

Here are the steps to make bibliography display for your LaTeX document:

**Install Biber**

On Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install biber
```

**Using `biber` as backend**

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
OR,
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

Then compilation should be done with the following commands (assuming your LaTeX file name is `myfile.tex`):

```
pdflatex myfile
biber myfile
pdflatex myfile
```

**Using `bibtex` as backend**

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```

Then you have to run the following commands to compile the file (`myfile.tex`):

```
pdflatex myfile
bibtex myfile
pdflatex myfile
```

Now, you should be able to see bibliography page when you open your pdf file (`myfile.pdf` in this example).

*Reference*: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=22023#p74103

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, they above answers did not work for me. So I provide an alternative, in case others experience the same issue:

Files:

```
report.tex
refs.bib
```

The relevant sections from `report.tex`:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
% For using bibtex
%
% The `noadjust` parameter turns off the behaviour when this package
% inserts spaces before references.
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}

\begin{document}
% ...
\bibliography{refs}{}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\end{document}
```

The compilation command is two-fold, that is I need to compile both with `pdflatex` and with `bibtex` - both are done from the (Linux-)terminal:

```bash
pdflatex report.tex
bibtex report.aux
pdflatex report.tex
```

This will, in my case, compile the reference database and properly display a list of references in the pdf-output.