# BibTeX bibliography not printing

Tags: bibtex

I was unable to find a previous post about this - perhaps too simple? I just came across the BibTeX and am trying to use it with an EndNote library. I have exported to the .bib file (which looks good as far as I can tell), but no bibliography is printed and the references aren't being cited. Obviously there is something major missing.  My document looks as follows.

```
\documentclass[11pt, fceqn]{article}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{setspace, titlesec, caption, floatrow}  

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm, cite, mathtools, lineno, subfig, natbib}

\begin{document} 

Some text \cite{Alo_1}.

\bibliography{bib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I changed the BibTeX commands option to bibtex.exe %.aux and it worked!

Comment: Related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135484/still-biblatex-will-not-print-bibliography

Answer (score 4):

After executing

```
latex mydocument.tex
```

a text file called `mydocument.aux` is created, besides the dvi output. This .aux file contains information about the bibliography. You need to run

```
bibtex mydocument.aux
```

to produce the proper `mydocument.bbl`, and then again

```
latex mydocument.tex
```

for the output to include the bibliography

Comment: Can this be done within my document using TexStudio? I'm unsure how to run this file manually. Thank you again!

Comment: I think my file name is okay, but I don't think the .bbl is being created. It's a place to start, thanks for the help!

Comment: The contents of the .log file produced after the build should help to determine the problem. You can also try to run the `latex bibtex latex` commands from the command line.

Comment: It should be unnecessary to specify `.aux` as the file extension for `bibtex`, and it's not necessary to specify `tex` as the file extension for `latex`. Hence, `latex mydocument`, `bibtex mydocument`, and twice more `latex mydocument` should suffice.