# natbib not printing bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'm trying to use natbib to get a bibliography, but it's not working. I tried compiling a sample tex-file, which worked fine, but in my document it's not happening. My document looks like this:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[12pt]{ociamthesis}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
---content with citations---
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

My bib-file looks like this:

```
@book{goossens93,
  author = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittlebach and Alexander Samarin",
  title = "The Latex Companion",
  year = "1993",
  publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
  address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
  }
```

It just completely ignores the bibliography, there's no headline or anything. Where I put the citations, it prints ?. I even tried stripping the document until only

```
\documentclass[12pt]{ociamthesis}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\cite{goossens93}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

remained, but it didn't help. When I created a new .tex-file in another directory with the same contents, it worked fine. Deleting everything but the *.tex-file also didn't help. Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using BibTeX?

Comment: I do not have your classfile, so I tried your MWE with `\documentclass{article}` and I did not encounter any problems.

Comment: Show the log-file and the blg-file of the compilation of the stripped down failing example.

Comment: Off-topic: The `subfigure` package is badly deprecated -- don't use it. In its stead, consider using either the `subfig` package or the `subcaption` package.

Answer (score 1):

Simply loading the `natbib` citation management package does *not* generate a formatted bibliography. The `natbib` package provides various citation-related commands and provides several bibliography styles, such as `plainnat`.

To actually generate the bibliography and correctly-formatted citation call-outs (to entries in the bibliography), you need to run BibTeX (after having first run LaTeX, of course) and then rerun LaTeX twice more.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in an answer to this question:
[BibTeX bibliography not printing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169113/bibtex-bibliography-not-printing/169114#169114)

I don't know why it wouldn't work otherwise for my document, because it worked fine for a fresh document, but it worked.

Comment: The information content of an observation such as "it worked fine for a fresh document" is nearly impossible to evaluate. For sure, there's an unlimited number of potential "fresh" documents, and without access to a specific such document it's not meaningful to speculate as to what is going on.