# bibliography is not printing in `amsart`

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am using the following code, but the bibliography is not printing. I checked all possible solutions like [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169113/bibtex-bibliography-not-printing), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135484/still-biblatex-will-not-print-bibliography?noredirect=1&lq=1) and many more. But I my problem did not get solved.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{Myref_bib}
\title{Temp}
\author{Author}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \section{Hello}
    hello hello hello hello  \cite{Abr70} 
    \section{ref not prinitng}
    \cite{AbWe02},\cite{Ada56}
    \printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

**Edit**

After compling with `biber`, I am getting the following:

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.14
INFO - Logfile is 'temp.tex.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find 'temp.tex.bcf'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1
biber: major issue: User/administrator updates are out-of-sync.
```

[image]

Can anyone please help me regrading this? I am using MikTeX and TeXStudio.

Comment: Did you already compile your document using `biber`?

Comment: See also: [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/134144)

Comment: @leandriis Yes, I have complied with `biber`.

Comment: As the error says: update your miktex in **both** miktex admin mode and miktex user mode.

Comment: @daleif I updated my packages in Miktex console, but still getting the same message. Even after opening the console I am getting a pop-up saying the same.

Comment: Also, replace `\bibliography`  with `\addbibresource`.

Comment: Nothing happened. Package updated, but getting the message `ERROR - Cannot find 'temp.tex.bcf'!`

Comment: @leandriis both works

Comment: Does it still say the last line? Can we see the bib file?

Comment: @daleif basically I was getting an error because I was using `biber temp.tex`. I tried `biber temp` and get the output. Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know TeXStudio is capable of running biber for you.

Comment: Yeah, intiially I don't know why TeXStudio was not compiling, but now everything is fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for getting TeXstudio to run Biber for you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem was solved by correcting the name of the file to be processed by biber, as noted in the comments.