# Generating a default LaTeX bibliography from existing BibTeX file

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, texmaker

unfortunately I cannot bring Texmaker to create a bibliography using BibTeX, so I was wondering: Can I create code that suits the needs of the default environment `\begin{thebibliography}` importing my `.bib` database? Is there an automatic procedure, any available piece of software?

Comment: The piece of software is bibtex (or newer biber). So you will have to learn how to use it. bibtex should work out of the box. Every decent tex editor has a bibtex menu.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can mark your text as code by selecting it and pressing the "{}" button. I removed your "thanks" as it does not fit our Answer&Response style of this page.

Comment: Texmaker can surely *help* with the creation of a bibliography, but it needs a `.tex` file that is doing the 'right things' (e.g., loading a `.bst`, loading a `.bib`, `\cite`-ing some entry keys from the `.bib`) before any bibliography can be generated.  You also need to run the correct sequence of commands (e.g., `latex`, `bibtex`, `latex`, `latex`) for it to work properly.  Thus a MWE would really be helpful in getting you the help you need...

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66201/15925