# BibTeX compiling but not working - shows question mark between brackets

Tags: bibtex, cite-package

I have this simple TeX file in TeXmaker.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

\title{My Article}
\author{Nobody Jr.}
\date{Today}
\maketitle

Blablabla said \cite{bertrand} and whatever.

\bibliography{endnotelibrary}{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

My file in `.bib` format is in the same folder as the TeX file.

```
   @article{bertrand
       author = {Bertrand, M. and Duflo, E. and Mullainathan, S.},
       title = {How Much Should We Trust Difference-In-Differences Estimates?},
       journal = {Quarterly Journal of Economics},
       volume = {119},
       pages = {249-275},
       year = {2004}
    }
```

I have set up my TeXMaker as the following:

`Options/Configure TexMaker/Quick Build/for asy files/wizard`

The quick build compiles running

> LaTeX --> BibTeX --> LaTeX --> LaTeX

again as recommended [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66201/how-do-i-set-up-my-latex-document-to-enable-me-to-cite-from-my-bibtex-bibliograp).

When I run the wizard and want to view the file in PDF format, in the citations I "[?]" instead.

The are warnings too in the Log:

```
Citation `bertrand' on page 1 undefined

`Empty `thebibliography' environment`
```

Although it is clearly defined as endnotelibrary!

I am saving my TeX files in a Dropbox folder. (Not sure if this has any relevance.)

[image]

Comment: What does the blg-file say?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't know what's the blg-file (Message/log window?). I have uploaded an screenshot to the question if that helps.

Comment: @Johannes_B I posted a question some days ago as I was building the bibtex library from endnote but other people helped me.

Comment: I run pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex. Now, I get the word "Reference" in bold as a chapter heading right below the sentence. In the command editor the cursor changed (an intermitent black box instead of the usual intermitent bar) but the [?] is still there. Is there anything else I could do?

Comment: Yeah, show us the blg file. On windows, you might need to toggle file endings. It will be there (if you have run bibtex) and you can open it with your LaTeX-editor.

Comment: @Johannes_B A comma after the last field is optional, but I recommend having it, so adding fields or moving them around will not cause harm.

Comment: The blg-file is a file with the extension `.blg` which is created by bibtex and shows if there were errors. It should be in the folder of your document (unless texmaker hides it somewhere). In cas that you are on windows: windows hides some extensions and it could be that it tells you that the file is a sort of message file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment:

Please try the following complete, compilable MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{bertrand,
  author  = {Bertrand, M. and Duflo, E. and Mullainathan, S.},
  title   = {How Much Should We Trust Difference-In-Differences Estimates?},
  journal = {Quarterly Journal of Economics},
  volume  = {119},
  pages   = {249-275},
  year    = {2004},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

\title{My Article}
\author{Nobody Jr.}
\date{Today}
\maketitle

Blablabla said \cite{bertrand} and whatever.
\nocite{*} %                              To check all bib entrys at once ...

\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

Package `filecontents` is only to put the bib file into the MWE to have only one file to compile.

The result then on my computer with current MiKTeX 2.9 is

[image]

If you got something else please add `\listfiles` as first line to the MWE, compile and add the new part in the log file to your question ...

Comment: I get the same result as you, your code works! I wonder why mine doesn't

Comment: @user3507584 Delete your .bbl file and recompile.

Comment: After reinstalling MikTeX and Texmaker several times, it is finally working. Not sure how it fixed it but it is something to consider if someone faces the same problem in the future.